# Linux filters GREP, AWK - Exclude know ORA- errors like obj exists etc

Tags: linux, oracle, database-migration, importerror

I'm trying to fix post migration, oracle data import/load and the logfile is huge to go through tons of known errors and few errors to manually fix.

How to,

- Filter/Exclude know errors,Include only required ORA-123 errors & failing sql blocks
- using linux grep/AWK cmnds and into a new file to read easily

**Errors to filter like few ORA-123 & few failing sql: ,**

1. ORA-123
2. Failing sql: Tablexx - CONVERSION ("xxx_OWNER"."tablexx" & xx_OWNER)

Comment: `grep -v`? Can you explain your problem with more details?

Comment: Exclude error which i can ignore , include rest ... the errors will be in the format 'ORA-XXX'  and also i want to grep/get statements starting with 'Failing sql'

Comment: That does not really make it any clearer. `grep -v | grep` should work perfectly fine or does this not cover some specific inputs of yours?

Answer (score 1):

I'll take a shot in the dark since the question does not clarify what the problem exactly is, but combining grep once with and once without `-v` should work just fine:

```bash
<inputfile grep -v 'ORA-123' | grep 'Failing sql'
```